# How to figure out concentration of ingredients in solution?

Tags: solutions

I have a solution that contains 3 inactive ingredients: ethanol, propylene glycol, purified water and 5% of an active ingredient.
What would be the smartest way to figure out the concentrations of the 3 inactive ingredients? Ideally something I can do at home without spending too much money.

Answer (score 3):

Smartest way would be to ask. Getting  the composition of 4-component mixture at home is not probable.

But some approximate estimations can be done if some basic measurement techniques are available.

If the active ingredient is not volatile, careful evaporation may give by the mass decrease the mass sum (alcohol + water) and (propylene glycol + the active one).

If the latter is (assumed) small enough, you can estimate alcohol content from the density as the ration of the mixture mass and volume, with some density correction for the nonvolatile rest(the best if its volume can be measured too).

**Illustrative example:** Let assume you were able to measure the required parameters:

- Let assign symbols P=product, W=water, A=alcohol, PG=propylene glycol, I = active ingredience.
- Let assign symbols $m_\text{P}$, $V_\text{P}$, $\rho_\text{P}$ to mass, volume and density of the product.
- Let assign symbols $m_\text{W}$, $V_\text{W}$, $\rho_\text{W}$ to mass, volume and density of the W+A product part.
- Let assign symbols $m_\text{I}$, $V_\text{I}$, $\rho_\text{I}$ to mass, volume and density of the PG+I product part.
- The volume $V_\text{P}=\pu{100 mL}$
- The mass $m_\text{P}=\pu{95 g}$
- The density $\rho_\text{P} =\frac{\pu{95 g}}{\pu{100 mL}} = \pu{0.95 g mL-1}$
- You have let it evaporate, freely or in water bath until it get about constant mass $m_\text{I}=\pu{10 g}$.
- That means, assuming the active ingredient is not volatile enough, the mass $m_\text{W}=m_\text{P} - m_\text{I}=\pu{95 g} - \pu{10 g}=\pu{85 g}$.
- [Propylene glycol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propylene_glycol) has density $\pu{1.036 g mL-1}$. For simplicity, let assume the same for the active ingredient, so $\rho_\text{I}=\pu{1.036 g mL-1}$
- Let assume approximation of volume additivity so if the product is mixed, then $V_\text{P} = V_\text{W} + V_\text{I}$.
- $V_\text{W} = V_\text{P} - V_\text{I} = V_\text{P} - m_\text{I}/\rho_\text{I}=\pu{100 mL} - \pu{10 g}/\pu{1.036 g mL-1} \approx \pu{90.3 mL}$
- Density of the W+A portion is then $\rho_\text{W}=m_\mathrm{W}/V_\mathrm{W}=\frac{\pu{85 g}}{\pu{90.3 ml}} \approx \pu{0.94 g mL-1}$
- From the [Ethanol-water density table](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ethanol-water-mixture-density-d_2162.html), it has weight percentage $w \approx 40\ \%$.

The contexct of the ingredients is then:

| Name | Mass |
| --- | --- |
| Water | $m_W \cdot 60 \%/100=\pu{51 g}$ |
| Alcohol | $m_W \cdot 40 \%/100=\pu{34 g}$ |
| Propylene glycol | $m_\text{I} - \pu{4.75 g} = \pu{5.25 g}$ |
| Active ingredient | $m_\text{P} \cdot 5 \%/100=\pu{4.75 g}$ |

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response! Just to recap: The idea is basically that PG has a lower evaporation rate than alcohol+water, so we can reduce the solution to PG + I only by evaporating all the A+W, correct? If so, how will I know when to stop the evaporation, i.e. when will I know I have reached the point where all A+W is gone? Btw, the active ingredient is Minoxidil, so 3g in a 60ml solution.

Comment: Recap: correct. It is expected to weight it periodically, when evaporation slows down, until it is like stops.

Comment: As it looks this is about medical application I advice against experimentation. I reserve myself right to refuse responsibility to any misuse and undesired effects, as I have warned you not to do so. Personal medical advices are explicit off topic on this site for these reasons.